# How can I make a Scattered chart in excel where the dots are different colors?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have the following info:

```
Question | Importance | Percentage
    1    |     2      |     15%
    2    |     1      |     98%
    3    |     1      |     35%
    4    |     3      |     22%
    5    |     2      |     43%
```

I want to display an scattered chart where the X-axis are the questions, the Y-Axis is the percentage and the dots have a color depending on the importance; for instance importance 1 is yellow, importance 2 is orange and importance 3 is red.

How can I make the dots in a scattered chart have a color depending on the importance automatically and not manual?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got an idea, but a question for you first, how many importance levels are there? Will that number ever change?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a pivot chart that is a line chart reformatted to look like a scatter chart.

First, pivot your data:

[image]

Next, with the pivot table selected, insert a line chart:

[image]

Third:  select each series in the line chart; choose "format data series",  choose "Line color" and select "no line."  The line chart now looks like a scatter chart:

[image]